# Change what I render based on checkbox input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a web app where a user can input some data and have it analyzed. If the user doesn't want to upload data and would rather see an example, I want to display an image rather than a plot. Is there a way to decide when to use `renderPlot` and `renderImage` based on user input? My solution so far is:

(in my `ui.R` inside of a fluid page):

```
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.useExample == true",
      imageOutput("allPCA.image")
      ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.useExample == false",
      plotOutput("allPCA.plot")
    )
```

And I have two functions in my output:

```
output$allPCA.image <- renderImage({
      list(src = "./static/pca.all.png",
           contentType = 'image/png',
           alt = "Example PCA")

    }, deleteFile=FALSE)

  output$allPCA.plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(stuff))}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following an answer for this example [renderImage NOT DISPLAYING - R Shiny (only alt text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332627/renderimage-not-displaying-r-shiny-only-alt-text) You can do the following:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Plot or Example?"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("my_choices", "Example or Plot",choices = c("Plot", "Example"), selected = 1),width=2),
      mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.my_choices == 'Plot'",
          plotOutput('my_test1')
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.my_choices == 'Example'",
          uiOutput("my_test2")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$my_test1 <- renderPlot({plot(runif(100))})
    output$my_test2 <- renderUI({
      images <- c("http://www.i2symbol.com/images/abc-123/o/white_smiling_face_u263A_icon_256x256.png")
      tags$img(src= images)
    })
  }
))
```